# How to access files out of app directory

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

I am developing an application which can list the phone files, such as a .pdf. But so far I could only read the files within the application directory.

The following code:

```
    let pathURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    let path = pathURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("file.pdf")
    let pathStr = path.path
    return pathStr
```

The above code works, but only for directories within the application directory and I need to read all directories and grab all the .pdf files.
How to get access to all phone directories? For example, read and catch all the .pdf files you have on your phone. If not, please indicate the link where the restriction list.

Comment: Is this mean for the App Store? If so, you can't. An app is sandboxed. You can only read your own app's files.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, it goes to the App Store. As Whatsapp can work this way? Or it only works with iCloud Drive?

Comment: A 3rd party app can access files from other services such as iCloud Drive, Dropbox, Google Drive, etc. But those files are not in the local iOS device. They are from outside services. Your app can access them like WhatsApp or any other 3rd party app. What your app can't do is find files on the local iOS device outside of your own app's sandbox.

Comment: @rmaddy very thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to Apple's sandboxing, you can only read documents in your own app's directory.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html):

> An iOS app’s interactions with the file system are limited mostly to the directories inside the app’s sandbox.